# TypeError: data.map is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this message in browser: TypeError: data.map is not a function

I am passing an array from another component here as props. What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

I guess it can be connected with `export default eventData` so that eventdata can be object but not array in this case

**event-data.js**

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
const eventType = ['Party', 'Karaoke', 'Concert'];

const monthObject = [
  { id: 'sort-by-month' },
  { name: 'By month' },
  { values: months },
];

const eventObject = [
  { id: 'sort-by-category' },
  { name: 'By category' },
  { values: eventType },
];

const eventData = { monthObject, eventObject };


event-filter-bar.js

import eventData from '../../data/event-data';

class EventFilterBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FilterToolbar data={eventData} />
    );
  }
}
```

**event-filter-bar.js**

```
import eventData from '../../data/event-data';

class EventFilterBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FilterToolbar data={eventData} />
    );
  }
}
```

**filter-toolbar.js**

```
class FilterToolbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar className="justify-content-center">
        <DropdownMaker data={data} />
        <DropdownWithDate />
        <ResetButton />
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

FilterToolbar.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

**dropdown-maker.js**

```
class DropdownMaker extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const eventFilters = data.map((e) => (
      <DropdownMenu
        id={e.id}
        name={e.name}
        values={e.values}
        key={e.id}
      />
    ));
    return (
      { eventFilters }
    );
  }
}

DropdownMaker.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: data is not an Array in that expression. Find out why and verify assumptions.

Comment: data is an object of two arrays, not an array

Comment: `eventData = { ... }`, so we don't expect `eventData` to have a `map` method. Did you want to make an array with two elements, `monthObject` and `eventObject`, or something else? Also, I strongly suspect you meant to make `monthObject` and `eventObject` each objects with three properties instead of array of one-property objects.

Comment: add ```export default eventData;``` at event-data.js file.

Comment: even this it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `monthObject` and `eventObject` are same data structure. So you can make an array of an object by combining these two, and export the array not object of two array at `event-data.js`. So your `event-data.js` should look like-

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
const eventType = ['Party', 'Karaoke', 'Concert'];

const eventData = [
    {
        id: 'sort-by-month',
        name: 'By month',
        values: months
    },
    {
        id: 'sort-by-category',
        name: 'By category',
        values: eventType 
    }
];

export default eventData;
```

Now you have the `data` array and `map` should work now.

**Update**
Update the `DropdownMaker` as

```
class DropdownMaker extends Component {
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
            data && data.length > 0 && data.map(e => {
                return (
                    <DropdownMenu
                        id={e.id}
                        name={e.name}
                        values={e.values}
                        key={e.id}
                    />
                )
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done so. But even now I see Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {eventFilters}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I guess 'export default eventData' exports object but not array

Comment: it works! thanx a lot!
i want to ask you to describe what this line means (i don't understand bold ones)?
**data** && data.length > 0 && **data.map**

Comment: It's just a security check if the data really exists and populated or not. If exists then map through it, otherwise return null.

Comment: What you did before by returning this ```{ eventFilters }``` is returning an object. You just needed to remove the curly-braces from the eventFilters I think.